# Finding the limit of a sequence 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find the limit of the following sequence and am not sure where to start. Any help would be great:

> $$
> a_n = (n^2 + 1)\sin\Bigl(\,\frac{1}{n^3+1}\Bigr)
>  + (n^2 + 2)\sin\Bigl(\,\frac{1}{n^3+2}\Bigr) + \dots
>  +(n^2 + n)\sin\Bigl(\,\frac{1}{n^3+n}\Bigr) 
> $$

Thanks

Comment: WolframAlpha tells me the limit is $1$ (e.g. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+i%3D1+to+100+of+(10000%2Bi)sin(1%2F(1000000%2Bi)))

Comment: As an upper bound you have $a_n \leq (n^3 + n^2)sin(\frac{1}{n^3+n}) $

Answer (score 2):

With $\sin x\leq x$ and $\sin x\geq x-x^{3}/6$ for small $0<x<1$, then 
\begin{align*}
a_{n}&\leq(n^{2}+1)\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}+1}\right)+\cdots+(n^{2}+n)\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}+n}\right)\\
&\leq\frac{n(n^{2}+n)}{n^{3}+1}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
a_{n}&\geq(n^{2}+1)\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}+1}\right)+\cdots+(n^{2}+n)\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}+n}\right)\\
&~~~~-\frac{1}{6}\left[(n^{2}+1)\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}+1}\right)^{3}+\cdots+(n^{2}+n)\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}+n}\right)^{3}\right]\\
&\geq\frac{n(n^{2}+1)}{n^{3}+n}-\frac{1}{6}\frac{n(n^{2}+n)}{(n^{3}+1)^{3}}.
\end{align*}
The rest is just Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Clever use of inequalities, +1

Comment: Having trouble wrapping my head around how this is starting off. I think I know what the squeeze theorem is however.